# How to set permissions to facebook properly with socialauth library?

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk, socialauth

I'm trying to limit the permissions to facebook. Here is what i called, but the permission are still the same (default - birthday, profile, post etc.). I only need post permissions.

```
adapter.addConfig(SocialAuthAdapter.Provider.FACEBOOK,"api_key","api_secret", "publish_actions");
```

After doing this the permissions doesn't change and the app gets rejected on facebook dev page because i need to provide information on where i use the rest of the permissions (like birthday, photos, profile etc.)
Am i'm doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only ask for publish permissions after you have been given basic_info.  You can not just do publish even if you are only going to publish.

Comment: i don't understand, can you please give some more details ?

Comment: When you say rejected on the Facebook dev page, do you mean when you try and create your app?  You should be able to configure it directly and not through the SocialAuth library.  I am not familiar with it.  When creating your app, you have to ask for public_profile which provides basic information about the user.